# GA event value, only INT?

Tags: google-analytics

So I am writing a custom PHP based event pusher to google analytics. I am kind of done, with only one caveat. It appears that analytics only accept 'value' parameter in integers. At first I thought that maybe I am supposed to send it as cent values. But no, if I send for example '50', what I see in the report is $50.00.

Any ways around it? Is there some extra configuration, I can pass? Because all the events that I need to implement, are in few cents range, so just rounding it up to nearest dollar, would lose all meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, event value is an int. Depending on your scenario setting a hit scoped custom metric with the type "currency" might be a workaround. This is not really the same, e.g. it will not be used in your Adwords ROAS calculations etc., but if you have only cents then this might not matter to you in any case.